# HTML5 native Drag 'n' Drop - Detect cancellation

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, detection, cancellation

I need to implement drag 'n' drop of HTML elements between browser windows.

When an element is dropped from window A to window B, it must be removed from window A (and added to window B).

When the drag 'n' drop is cancelled (happens when the user presses the "esc" key, or sometimes when the drag 'n' drop feature seems to bug), the element must go back to its original location.

Currently what I'm doing is to keep a "hasBeenDropped" flag, which is set to false in dragstart, and to true in drop. In dragend, I check my flag, and if it is not set to true, it means that the drop has fired in another window, or that the operation has been cancelled. I need to distinguish these two cases (drop in another window vs cancel), in order to act accordingly (eg remove the window or replace it to its original location).

TL;DR : I need to be able to detect when a native HTML5 drag 'n' drop operation has been cancelled (for example when a user presses "esc" key).

Is there any way to do so??

Comment: Any luck here? I just ran into this myself. I have the exact kind of housekeeping flag that you are retaining to track a successful drop, but differentiating between the different modes of cancellation is similarly required for our application. I tried to carefully examine the events to look for something to key off of, but so far I've only had luck with firefox.

Comment: Sorry, seems there is no way at the moment. I changed my job since, so I'm no longer working on this, but I did not manage to get it working as I wanted to. IIRC what I did was to make a copy instead of a move (doing so, the origin window doesn't need the drop event).

Answer (score 13):

Like you, I used a flag to determine whether or not a drop had successfully occurred elsewhere, which more or less implies that it hasn't been cancelled. However there appears to be a more proper way, as described in MDN:

> Finishing a Drag
>
> Once the drag is complete, a dragend event is fired at the source of
>   the drag (the same element that received the dragstart event). This
>   event will fire if the drag was successful[1] or if it was cancelled.
>   However, you can use the dropEffect property to determine what drop
>   operation occurred.
>
> If the dropEffect property has the value none during a dragend, then the drag was cancelled. Otherwise, the effect specifies which
>   operation was performed. The source can use this information after a
>   move operation to remove the dragged item from the old location. The
>   mozUserCancelled property will be set to true if the user cancelled
>   the drag (by pressing Escape), and false if the drag was cancelled for
>   other reasons such as an invalid drop target, or if it was successful.

The mozilla specific property is obviously undesirable, but the dropEffect property itself should be sufficient for most purposes. I tested it myself (tiles being dragged into dropzones within an iframe) and it seemed to work as expected.

This is taken directly from the current MDN page on the topic:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_operations#dragend

Probably not so useful to you since you switched jobs, but information on this topic is very difficult to find, so hopefully the next person searching will benefit.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, seems indeed the way to go. I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thanks , it really helped.

Comment: For those (like me) too lazy to follow the link: `dropEffect` is a property of [`DataTransfer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer#Standard_properties) and not of the event, i.e. use `ev.dataTransfer` (or `ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer` when using jQuery).

Answer (score -1):

The dragend event is fired when a drag operation is being ended (by releasing a mouse button or hitting the escape key).
You can check the event property "ctrlKey". If it is true, the Esc button was pressed. You can also check other properties if necessary.
Have a look at the reference, for example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragend

Best, Alex

Comment: Thanks, but the ctrlKey is false when cancelling the operation with esc key (at least for me, on Firefox, Chrome & Safari), which is normal.

Comment: Hi Tim, yes, right. Seems i mixed it up, sorry. So then I would use the drop event and go and look if you can detect the window by using target or view properties of the drop event. I would hope that you can use them for getting the element to which are you dropping or the window you are dropping to. Did you already have a look at that?

Comment: Good idea, I didn't check that. But unfortunately it doesn't work either, the target element is always the dragged HTML element, and the view is always the current window (if I drag from window A to window B, I get window A in window A dragend and window B in window B drop. I would need to get window B in window A dragend).

Comment: Ok, could you provide a online example or jsfiddle where I can check and elaborate the issue?